# Motion input in Simmechanics Matlab.

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulator

I have this figure in which motion is given to revolute joint in Simmechanics. [image]

In this, constant 2 is used and then integration is used. I want to  know what will be effect of 2 here and how integration is happening. What is the actual value of input here. Is it 2 degree or 2 degree/sec or something else. Is 2 is the upper limit of motion or lower limit? What will happen if replace 2 with 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 represents a constant acceleration of the revolute joint. It's unit of measure cannot be determined from this screenshot, since it is a parameter of the joint actuator (to my knowledge it can be set to deg/sec^2 or rad/sec^2).

It effect is a constant acceleration to the joint. Let's assume that in the joint actuator block the unit of measure is set to deg/s^2. It this case your mechanism will rotate with an increasing velocity. After 1 second of simulation time the velocity will be 2 deg/s. After 2 seconds of simulation time its velocity will be 4 deg/s. and so on. There is no limit to what the velocity will reach, the longer the simulation time the faster your mechanism will spin.